# Regex to find mp3 html file

Tags: c++, c, regex, visual-studio-2012, window

I am trying to match all the mp3s links in the html

expected output

```
http://mp3cofe.com/ariana-grande-weeknd-love-me-harder-andreevskiy-remix.mp3
http://mp3cofe.com/listen/52d-remix.mp3
```

getting output

```
http://mp3cofe.com/ariana-grande-weeknd-love-me-harder-andreevskiy-remix.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="color:green;">Download</a</div><a href="http://mp3cofe.com/listen/52d-remix.mp3"
```

code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
int main(){
    std::string subject("<a href=\"http://mp3cofe.com/ariana-grande-weeknd-love-me-harder-andreevskiy-remix.mp3\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:green;\">Download</a></div><a href=\"http://mp3cofe.com/listen/52d-remix.mp3\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:green;\">Download</a> ");
        std::regex re("(http:\/\/)(.*)(\.mp3\"\ )");
        std::sregex_iterator next(subject.begin(), subject.end(), re);
        std::sregex_iterator end;
        while (next != end) {
            std::smatch match = *next;
            std::cout << match.str() << "\n";
            next++;
        } 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `.*` is greedy by default. It matches all the characters greedily as much as possible.

```
std::regex re("(http://)(.*?)([.]mp3\" )");
```

Use the below regex if you don't want to include `"<space>` at the last.

```
std::regex re("(http://)(.*?)[.]mp3(?=\" )");
```

Comment: or use `\\S*` instead of `(.*?)`